# How to record audio from several microphones on OS X?

Tags: macos, core-audio, audio-recording

I tried `AudioQueueNewInput`. But there is no any way to specify audio input. I guess it uses default mic. How can I record audio from two mics simultaneously?

Comment: I believe you do understand the difference between _microphones_ and _input hardware devices_. Is your question about several microphones connected to the same hardware device or is it about programmatically combining, mixing and recording simultaneous input streams from different hardware devices?

Answer (score 0):

The Audio Queue API is a higher level API that abstracts a single (possibly stereo/multichannel) input source.  The lower level Audio Unit API will give you access to more input sources (microphones).